# Behaviours of new constructor added by AspectJ ITD

Tags: aop, aspectj

I am currently applying AspectJ to our project, and I found a behavior which is a bit strange to me.

**Q1:**
I added a new constructor to my current class with inter-type declaration, and found that the class's member variable is not initialized if the new constructor is used to instantiate my class.

For example:

The class which I'll add a new constructor to:

```
public class Child {

    public String name = "John";

    public Child(String desc) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
}
```

The aspectJ code:

```
public aspect MyTest {
    public Child.new(String desc, int num) {
        System.out.println("Child Name:" + this.name);
    }
}
```

If I instantiate the Child with the new constructor:

```
new Child("A child", 5)
```

the member variable **this.name** is not initialized as will be done with the original constructor.

But, if I call the original constructor:

```
new Child("A child")
```

the member variable **this.name** will be initialized to "John" as usual

The result:

> Child Name:null

**Is this a limitation of AspectJ? Is there anyway to resolve this issue?**

I don't really want to add the code for member variable initialization to the new constructor.

**Q2:**
It seems **in the newly added constructor**, **super.method()** can not be correctly resolved.

The class which I'll add a new constructor to:

```
public class Child extends Parent{

    public String name = "John";

    public Child(String desc) {

    }
}
```

**Child** extends **Parent**. **Parent** has a method **init()**

```
public class Parent {

    public void init() {
        //....
    }

}
```

I add a new constructor for the **Child** in my aspect.

```
public aspect MyTest {
    public Child.new(String desc, int num) {
        super.init();
    }
}
```

The above aspect code will trigger an exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.test2.Child.ajc$superDispatch$com_test2_Child$init()V
    at MyTest.ajc$postInterConstructor$MyTest$com_test2_Child(MyTest.aj:19)
    at com.test2.Child.<init>(Child.java:1)
    at MainProgram.main(MainProgram.java:11)
```

My workaround is to define **another method** for my class **Child**, and indirectly call the super.method() within that method

For example, add a new method that calls **super.init()** for **Child**

```
public void Child.initState()
{
    super.init();
}
```

Now, I can call initState() in the newly added constructor like below:

```
public aspect MyTest {
    public Child.new(String desc, int num) {
        this.initState();
    }
}
```

**Is this a limitation of AspectJ? Is this the only way to resolve this issue?**

Thank you all for your time :)

Comment: hi is anyone familiar with aspectj ? Any information is welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second question, I think it's a bug of aspectJ.
That decompile the woven target byte code will find that the method “com.test2.Child.ajc$superDispatch$com_test2_Child$init()V” will be inserted. It implies this method should be generate by aspectJ, but there is no such method in the byte code.

Answer (score 2):

Foe the first questions, it seems that the lint warning will appear when compiling:
(unless you close the lint warning)

**"inter-type constructor does not contain explicit constructor call: field initializers in the target type will not be executed [Xlint:noExplicitConstructorCall]"**

Therefore I'd say it's an **AspectJ's limitation**.

The best way to do this might be *call the other constructors of **Child*** in the constructor added by AspectJ

For example:

```
public aspect MyTest {
    public Child.new(String desc, int num) {
        this("Hello"); // -> This will call the constructor of Child, and trigger fields initialization
        System.out.println("Child Name:" + this.name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code for an ITD introduction is no different that the code that you would add to a class directly. So without member initialization code in your introduced constructor, members will , of course, remain uninitialized. So you need to change you code in Q1 as follows.

```
public Child.new(String name, int age) {
    this.name = name;
    this.age = age;
    System.out.println("Child Name:" + this.name);
}
```

As for Q2, it works fine for me.

```
class Parent {
    public void init() {
    System.out.println("P.init");
}
}

class Child extends Parent {
}

aspect Intro {
    public void Child.init(){
        super.init();
        System.out.println("C.init");
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child c = new Child();
        c.init();
    }
}
```

prints:

```
P.init
C.init
```

Changing the introduced method to something other than `init` works too (to match your code).

Regarding your comment: I fail to see what difference you have made in Q1. Sorry, I don't get it.

As for Q2 part of your comment, constructor arrangement works for me:

```
class Parent {
    protected String name;

    public Parent(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    int age;

    public Child(String name) {
        super(name);
    }
}

aspect Intro {
    public Child.new(String name, int age){
        super(name);
        this.age = age;
        System.out.println("this.name: " + this.name + " this.age: " + this.age);
    }
}
```

prints `this.name: myname this.age: 2`

Comment: hi ramnivas! thanks for your response, but I think you misunderstand my questions. Let's express them again.

In Q1: the Child's name field should be initialized if it's created by its original constructor.
But in the newly added constructor, Child's name field is not initialized.

Q2: The issue lies in the fact that super.method() can not be correctly resolved in the newly added constructor.

In your example, you add a plan method by ITD not a constructor

Comment: I've made some modifications to my questions to make it clearer, thank you